How to deal with temperature drift when computing thermal conductivity with molecular dynamics?
Background
In the $NVE$ ensemble, thermal conductivity, $\lambda_T$, can be computed from molecular dynamics (MD) using the Green-Kubo relation (Allen and Tildesley)
$$\lambda_T = \frac{V}{k_B T^2} \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}t \left \langle j_{\alpha}^{\epsilon}(t) j_{\alpha}^{\epsilon}(0) \right \rangle.$$
Here, $j_{\alpha}^{\epsilon}$ is a component of the energy current and $T$ is understood to be the ensemble average of temperature in the $NVE$ ensemble (or just the time average for an ergodic system).
Problem
Whenever we do MD in the $NVE$ ensemble with a finite time step, temperature will drift linearly with time due to discretization errors. Thus, while Green-Kubo demands long simulation times for averaging, the average temperature will never stabilize. How do we deal with this, practically speaking?
Possible Solutions?

If we reduce the time step, we reduce the amount of energy drift in the system. However, not only will this make simulations take longer, it still does not allow for arbitrarily long simulations because drift will inevitably present over time.
If we first equilibrate the system in another ensemble with a thermostat, the temperature is well-defined. Then, after switching to $NVE$, we can just ignore the temperature drift and only extract the energy autocorrelation. However, I am not sure if doing this is totally justified.


Are you using a symplectic integrator to integrate your equation of motion? If yes, I'm surprised there is an energy or temperature drift?

Yes, I’m using velocity Verlet. To my knowledge, energy drift is a fundamental feature of discrete dynamics with harmonic energy contributions; this is because any error in position is biased to increase energy on average.
